# Custom template tag - return objects

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I have a base.html which is inherited by all other pages. and the footer of all pages are also coming from base.html

now i want to show in footer some objects from db. so i need to render some objects from db to base.html. then i thought, i will write my own tag which does the job.

i did this custom tag:

```
def berlin_tag():
  loc_berlin = Location.objects.filter(stadt="Berlin").order_by('-id')[:4]
  return loc_berlin
```

I am returning 4 recent locations in berlin.

then in my template:

```
{% berlin_tag %}
```

but now i am stuck how to show it in template. at the moment, `{% berlin_tag %}` is showing `[, , ]`.

how can i loop over all 4 objects and show them in template? please help

Comment: What is type of your custom tag? Is it `simple_tag` or `inclusion_tag` or what?

Comment: @AamirAdnan, simple_tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assignment tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/) do exactly this.